# I need to show data from database to dropdown modal CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to show data from the database to dropdown.

This is what I have tried:

Model.php

```
public function get_province()
{
    $this->db->order_by('provincename');    
    $query = $this->db->get('tblprovince');

    return $query->result_array();

}
```

Controller.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('placemodel','tblplace');
    $this->load->model('placemodel', 'tblprovince', TRUE);
}

public function index()
{
    $data['provinces'] = $this->tblprovince->get_province();
    $data = array('title' => 'Places'); 
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');      
    $this->load->view('places/index',$data);
}

public function ajax_list()
{

    $list = $this->tblplace->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $place) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $no;
        $row[] = $place->placename;
        $row[] = $place->provincename;
        $row[] = $place->placetypename;
        $row[] = $place->tel;


        //add html for action
        $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_person('."'".$place->placeid."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_person('."'".$place->placeid."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->tblplace->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->tblplace->count_filtered(),
                    "data" => $data,
            );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

View.php

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Province</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">                                
                        <select name="province_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Province</option>
                                 <?php foreach ($provinces as $province): ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $province['provinceid']; ?>"><?php echo $province['provincename']; ?></option>
                                 <?php endforeach; ?>    
                        </select>
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

But the results not appear on province modal. It's not appearing on the dropdown list.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: replace $data = array('title' => 'Places'); by $data['title'] =  'Places';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your data array overwrites after you assign value for `provinces`
change your index method to

```
public function index()
{    
    $data = array('title' => 'Places'); 
    $data['provinces'] = $this->tblprovince->get_province(); // place here
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');      
    $this->load->view('places/index',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need assign array before provinces variable . 
It is assigned after `$data['provinces']`
so now `$data` have only this value array('title' => 'Places');

```
public function index()
{
    $data['provinces'] = $this->tblprovince->get_province();
    $data = array('title' => 'Places'); 
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');      
    $this->load->view('places/index',$data);
}
```